Tri-State Checkbox, Checkbox with triple status?
I have a problem... I don't know much about HTML, CSS or Javascript and I'm practicing to know more and I set as a challenge to make a kind of book like the one of phasmophobia that has in the selection of the ghost 3 states to mark that tests has given the ghost, without state, marked (it puts a circle around the checkbox text) and crossed out (you discard that test with a line that crosses out the text of the checkbox).
The problem is that I don't know how to do this, I tried many different ways but I can't find any way to make three states, one without anything, another one that makes a circle around the text of my checkbox and another one that crosses it out.
I would like to have a way to make it similar to the checkboxes that appear at the top of the book and another like at the bottom but with the top shape I would be more than happy.
Phasmophobia book

I made this: https://codepen.io/jonathan-diez/pen/YzVaWvY but although it works as I wanted it is not as I really wanted, I wanted that instead of green it was an X and that instead of red it was a line crossing out, in short, like the photo that I put of phasmophobia book above.
